Why RTU bridge timeout even though answer is received?
I'm testing the following code as a bridge between https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/ and https://pypi.org/project/pyModSlave/.
As hardware, I'm using a NodeMCU 1.0 and a USB/TTL converter.
The Modbus library is https://github.com/emelianov/modbus-esp8266.
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#include <ModbusTCP.h>
#include <ModbusRTU.h>

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <StreamBuf.h>

#define BSIZE 1024

const unsigned long baudrate = 19200;
const unsigned long chtimeus = (8 + 3) * 1000000 / baudrate;

ModbusRTU rtu;
ModbusTCP tcp;

IPAddress srcIp;

SoftwareSerial debug_serial(D1, D2);

uint8_t serialw_rtur[BSIZE];
uint8_t serialr_rtuw[BSIZE];

StreamBuf serialw_rtur_sb(serialw_rtur, BSIZE);
StreamBuf serialr_rtuw_sb(serialr_rtuw, BSIZE);

DuplexBuf modbus_db(&serialw_rtur_sb, &serialr_rtuw_sb);
DuplexBuf serial_db(&serialr_rtuw_sb, &serialw_rtur_sb);

uint8_t com_buf[BSIZE];
uint8_t log_buf[BSIZE];

StreamBuf com_sbuf(com_buf, BSIZE);
StreamBuf log_sbuf(log_buf, BSIZE);

uint16_t transRunning = 0;
uint8_t slaveRunning = 0;

bool cbRtuTrans(Modbus::ResultCode event, uint16_t transactionId, void* data) {
  if (event != Modbus::EX_SUCCESS) {
    debug_serial.printf("modbusRTU transaction result: %02X\n\r", event);
    transRunning = 0;
  }
  return true;
}

Modbus::ResultCode cbTcpRaw(uint8_t* data, uint8_t len, void* custom) {
  auto src = (Modbus::frame_arg_t*) custom;
  
  debug_serial.print("received a TCP request from ");
  debug_serial.print(IPAddress(src->ipaddr));
  debug_serial.printf("-> Fn: %02X, len: %d\n\r", data[0], len);

  if (transRunning) {
    tcp.setTransactionId(src->transactionId);
    tcp.errorResponce(IPAddress(src->ipaddr), (Modbus::FunctionCode)data[0], Modbus::EX_SLAVE_DEVICE_BUSY);
    return Modbus::EX_SLAVE_DEVICE_BUSY;
  }

  rtu.rawRequest(src->unitId, data, len, cbRtuTrans);
  
  if (!src->unitId) {
    tcp.setTransactionId(src->transactionId);
    tcp.errorResponce(IPAddress(src->ipaddr), (Modbus::FunctionCode)data[0], Modbus::EX_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    transRunning = 0;
    slaveRunning = 0;
    return Modbus::EX_ACKNOWLEDGE;
  }
  
  srcIp = IPAddress(src->ipaddr);
  
  slaveRunning = src->unitId;
  
  transRunning = src->transactionId;
  
  return Modbus::EX_SUCCESS;  
  
}

Modbus::ResultCode cbRtuRaw(uint8_t* data, uint8_t len, void* custom) {
  auto src = (Modbus::frame_arg_t*)custom;
  
  debug_serial.printf("received RTU response from %d-> Fn: %02X, len: %d\n\r", src->slaveId, data[0], len);

  tcp.setTransactionId(transRunning);
  uint16_t succeed = tcp.rawResponce(srcIp, data, len, slaveRunning);
  if (!succeed) {
    debug_serial.print("failed to");
  }

  debug_serial.print("respond to TCP: ");
  debug_serial.println(srcIp);

  transRunning = 0;
  slaveRunning = 0;
  return Modbus::EX_PASSTHROUGH;
}

void print_log(const char *msg) {
  debug_serial.print(msg);
  debug_serial.print(": ");
  while(log_sbuf.available()) {
    debug_serial.print(log_sbuf.read(), HEX);
    debug_serial.print(' ');    
  }
  debug_serial.println();
}

void process_from_to(Stream *from_s, Stream *to_s, unsigned delay_us = 0) {
  while(from_s->available()) {
    
    char c = from_s->read();

    com_sbuf.write(c);
    log_sbuf.write(c);

    if(delay_us != 0)
      delayMicroseconds(delay_us);

  }

  while(com_sbuf.available())
    to_s->write(com_sbuf.read());
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(baudrate, SERIAL_8E1);
  debug_serial.begin(baudrate, SWSERIAL_8E1);

  WiFi.begin("<SSID>", "<PASSWORD>");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    debug_serial.print(".");
  }

  debug_serial.println("");
  debug_serial.println("IP address: ");
  debug_serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  tcp.server();
  tcp.onRaw(cbTcpRaw);

  rtu.begin((Stream*)&modbus_db);
  rtu.master();
  rtu.onRaw(cbRtuRaw);
}

void loop() {
  rtu.task();
  tcp.task();
  yield();

  if(Serial.available()) {

    process_from_to(&Serial, &serial_db, chtimeus << 1);

    print_log("received response from RTU");

  }

  if(serial_db.available()) {

    process_from_to(&serial_db, &Serial);

    print_log("sent request to RTU");

  }

}

qModMaster has the following configs:

Modbus Mode: TCP
Slave Addr: 1
Scan Rate: 5 s
Function Code: 0x03
Start Address: 0x00
Register Number: 10
Slave IP: my ESP's IP in the network
Slave Port: 502

pyModSlave has the following configs:

Modbus Mode: RTU
Slave Address: 1
SimCycle: 5 s
Port: my ESP's Serial's USB port
Baudrate: 19200
Data Bits: 8
Stop Bits: 1
Parity: None

I've already tried using hard and soft Serial, baudrates of 9600 and 19200 and powering the board with a regulated supply @5V - 1A.
Both programs work normally when I communicate them directly with the ESP, either reading from the RTU slave or receiving reads from the TCP client.
When I use ESP as a bridge, the RTU slave receives the request normally and responds correctly in <5ms, but the timeout occurs.
An external monitor (a Uno with the Rx of a SoftwareSerial connected to the NodeMCU hardware Rx pin) shows that the correct data reaches the ESP:
rtu monitor:
[RTU]>Rx > 18:21:37:626 - 01 03 00 00 00 0A C5 CD 
[RTU]>Tx > 18:21:37:626 - 01 03 14 9D AC D8 0D 61 1A 29 7B 0E 7D 19 15 62 01 C2 F1 9E CF 41 C6 3C D4 
[RTU]>Rx > 18:21:47:674 - 01 03 00 00 00 0A C5 CD 
[RTU]>Tx > 18:21:47:675 - 01 03 14 A7 EE 7E F2 5D 43 66 D7 4B 73 3A 0A D2 B6 23 BB F0 E4 AB D0 CD 9E 
[RTU]>Rx > 18:21:57:590 - 01 03 00 00 00 0A C5 CD 
[RTU]>Tx > 18:21:57:590 - 01 03 14 D0 31 DC 14 E7 A2 84 49 C6 3A 1D 13 BD 7E DD DF E1 C7 02 89 F0 80 
[RTU]>Rx > 18:22:07:638 - 01 03 00 00 00 0A C5 CD 
[RTU]>Tx > 18:22:07:639 - 01 03 14 71 26 FE 5B 12 23 A7 F4 39 0A 55 12 F9 E4 63 27 90 0C 18 11 00 51 
[RTU]>Rx > 18:22:17:682 - 01 03 00 00 00 0A C5 CD 
[RTU]>Tx > 18:22:17:683 - 01 03 14 1C 9D A1 68 11 71 A4 96 1D BF D4 C3 86 B1 B2 42 68 C4 72 BD C6 A3 
[RTU]>Rx > 18:22:27:722 - 01 03 00 00 00 0A C5 CD 
[RTU]>Tx > 18:22:27:724 - 01 03 14 93 6B 28 A4 F2 DD 3D E1 C3 29 61 82 EF CC E3 37 99 AA 32 04 3A 56 

external monitor:
response: 1 3 14 9D AC D8 D 61 1A 29 7B E 7D 19 15 62 1 C2 F1 9E CF 41 C6 3C D4
response: 1 3 14 A7 EE 7E F2 5D 43 66 D7 4B 73 3A A D2 B6 23 BB F0 E4 AB D0 CD 9E
response: 1 3 14 D0 31 DC 14 E7 A2 84 49 C6 3A 1D 13 BD 7E DD DF E1 C7 2 89 F0 80
response: 1 3 14 71 26 FE 5B 12 23 A7 F4 39 A 55 12 F9 E4 63 27 90 C 18 11 0 51
response: 1 3 14 1C 9D A1 68 11 71 A4 96 1D BF D4 C3 86 B1 B2 42 68 C4 72 BD C6 A3
response: 1 3 14 93 6B 28 A4 F2 DD 3D E1 C3 29 61 82 EF CC E3 37 99 AA 32 4 3A 56

bridge monitor:
received a TCP request from 192.168.1.12-> Fn: 03, len: 5
sent request to RTU: 1 3 0 0 0 A C5 CD 
received response from RTU: 1 20 51 C6 C3 D 58 A3 69 39 7D 46 91 5 C2 7C F6 41 1C A2 
received a TCP request from 192.168.1.12-> Fn: 03, len: 5
modbusRTU transaction result: E4

received a TCP request from 192.168.1.12-> Fn: 03, len: 5
sent request to RTU: 1 3 0 0 0 A C5 CD 
received response from RTU: 1 20 D1 73 7E BE 35 99 D7 A9 E9 A 3A DB DA F0 DE D D7 9E 

received a TCP request from 192.168.1.12-> Fn: 03, len: 5
modbusRTU transaction result: E4

received a TCP request from 192.168.1.12-> Fn: 03, len: 5
sent request to RTU: 1 3 0 0 0 A C5 CD 
received response from RTU: 1 20 11 17 E2 14 9E 23 49 9C EA 13 6F 75 DF 78 9C 89 80 
received a TCP request from 192.168.1.12-> Fn: 03, len: 5
modbusRTU transaction result: E4

received a TCP request from 192.168.1.12-> Fn: 03, len: 5
sent request to RTU: 1 3 0 0 0 A C5 CD 
received response from RTU: 1 20 51 99 FE 2B 34 3A F4 4E A1 95 94 E4 AC 12 C6 18 44 51 
received a TCP request from 192.168.1.12-> Fn: 03, len: 5
modbusRTU transaction result: E4

received a TCP request from 192.168.1.12-> Fn: 03, len: 5
sent request to RTU: 1 3 0 0 0 A C5 CD 
received response from RTU: 1 20 11 D4 A1 2B 14 91 96 47 A3 C3 58 93 42 8B 72 6F DC FF 
received a TCP request from 192.168.1.12-> Fn: 03, len: 5
modbusRTU transaction result: E4

received a TCP request from 192.168.1.12-> Fn: 03, len: 5
sent request to RTU: 1 3 0 0 0 A C5 CD 
received response from RTU: 1 20 D1 B6 A1 A4 BE D7 A C3 4A 9 EF 6E 37 66 35 22 3A F5 
received a TCP request from 192.168.1.12-> Fn: 03, len: 5
modbusRTU transaction result: E4

tcp monitor
[TCP]>Tx > 18:21:37:517 - 00  16  00  00  00  06  01  03  00  00  00  0A  
Sys > 18:21:38:031 - Error : Timeout
[TCP]>Tx > 18:21:42:523 - 00  17  00  00  00  06  01  03  00  00  00  0A  
[TCP]>Rx > 18:21:42:649 - 00  17  00  00  00  03  FF  83  06  
Sys > 18:21:42:649 - Error : Slave device or server is busy
[TCP]>Tx > 18:21:47:524 - 00  18  00  00  00  06  01  03  00  00  00  0A  
Sys > 18:21:48:039 - Error : Timeout
[TCP]>Tx > 18:21:52:525 - 00  19  00  00  00  06  01  03  00  00  00  0A  
[TCP]>Rx > 18:21:52:684 - 00  19  00  00  00  03  FF  83  06  
Sys > 18:21:52:684 - Error : Slave device or server is busy
[TCP]>Tx > 18:21:57:521 - 00  1A  00  00  00  06  01  03  00  00  00  0A  
Sys > 18:21:58:027 - Error : Timeout
[TCP]>Tx > 18:22:02:536 - 00  1B  00  00  00  06  01  03  00  00  00  0A  
[TCP]>Rx > 18:22:02:595 - 00  1B  00  00  00  03  FF  83  06  
Sys > 18:22:02:595 - Error : Slave device or server is busy
[TCP]>Tx > 18:22:07:543 - 00  1C  00  00  00  06  01  03  00  00  00  0A  
Sys > 18:22:08:044 - Error : Timeout
[TCP]>Tx > 18:22:12:539 - 00  1D  00  00  00  06  01  03  00  00  00  0A  
[TCP]>Rx > 18:22:12:633 - 00  1D  00  00  00  03  FF  83  06  
Sys > 18:22:12:633 - Error : Slave device or server is busy
[TCP]>Tx > 18:22:17:542 - 00  1E  00  00  00  06  01  03  00  00  00  0A  
Sys > 18:22:18:047 - Error : Timeout
[TCP]>Tx > 18:22:22:531 - 00  1F  00  00  00  06  01  03  00  00  00  0A  
[TCP]>Rx > 18:22:22:577 - 00  1F  00  00  00  03  FF  83  06  
Sys > 18:22:22:577 - Error : Slave device or server is busy
[TCP]>Tx > 18:22:27:536 - 00  20  00  00  00  06  01  03  00  00  00  0A  
Sys > 18:22:28:041 - Error : Timeout
[TCP]>Tx > 18:22:32:534 - 00  21  00  00  00  06  01  03  00  00  00  0A  
[TCP]>Rx > 18:22:32:595 - 00  21  00  00  00  03  FF  83  06  
Sys > 18:22:32:595 - Error : Slave device or server is busy

Please, any hint on what to test or what else to investigate? Thanks.

You think that you were receiving something via TCP, but if you look at "received response" from the log, it is totally rubbish and just doesn't make any sense. While the data from RTU has the correct data format and CRC.

No idea where you get the Modbus library from, so can't comment anything whether the library could handle both TCP and RTU simultaneously. One thing about your code is that if  it received error or busy there is no re-send or waitWhileBusy mechanism, and your code didn't really handle any Modbus Exception, you simply went straight to print the buffer and thinking that's what you received...

Thank you for the feedback. I've edited the question to inform the used library (https://github.com/emelianov/modbus-esp8266) and provide clearer debug messages.
